# How to make atom-typescript recognize modules without relative path?

Tags: typescript, angular, atom-editor, angular-meteor, tsconfig

I'm following [angular-meteor tutorial using angular2 and typescript](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping).

Since I'm using atom, I added atom-typescript package and a `tsconfig` file to take advantage of type declaration files.

I'm trying to make atom-typescript recognize the import on `client/parties-form/parties_form.ts`:

```
import {Parties} from  'collections/parties';
```

But atom give me the following error : `Cannot find module 'collections/parties'.`

Error goes off when I import the module with relative path :

```
import {Parties} from '../../collections/parties';
```

But then meteor wont compile and gives me a `Path reservation conflict` error.

I'd like to be able to use the first kind of import without atom-typescript giving me any error and hence recognizing my type declaration files. What did I miss ?

My `tsconfig.json` file :

```
{
    "version": "1.5.0",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./**/*.ts",
        "!./typings/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

Full version of the tutorial code can be found [here](https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular2.0-socially/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `import {Parties} from '../../collections/parties';`

This requirement is *not specific to atom-typescript*. Non relative paths for *your own code outside node_modules* is not supported in TypeScript. Track this issue for details : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039

Comment: I have webpack handling the imports, is there anyway to suppress that error message in atom (my app runs perfectly so it isn't a real error)

Comment: Use TypeScript's "baseUrl" option in compiler settings. So for example, if your code is in `src` `"baseUrl": "./src"`

Comment: Oops! Also need to add `"rootDirs": ["./src"]`